# What happens to my Schengen visa application being processed during coronavirus?

Tags: schengen, europe, schengen-visas, netherlands, covid-19

I submitted my application a week ago, before the COVID-19 pandemic was declared.

I am just wondering whether they can reject my application because of coronavirus, or would they still issue me a visa but advise me not to travel?

I had applied for the Netherlands.

Comment: What were the intended dates of travel? If you were planning to travel in the next 30 days, not only will they advise you not to travel, but you simply won't be allowed to enter the EU or Schengen Area, a ban is in place since noon today. As to what they will actually do, how, and when, I think your best bet at the moment is to (try to) ask them...

Comment: @R.B. When were you hoping to travel? The travel ban will last for at least a month from today  https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/macron-confirms-all-external-internal-schengen-borders-will-close-on-tuesday-at-noon/

Comment: Did you check on the embassy website? Probably the visa will not be issued, but it is not a rejection. Maybe you get two possibilities: cancel application or just wait. These are uncharted waters, so the rules could change quickly.

Comment: The Schengen Visa Code does forsee conditions where a visa will not be issued (or application not accepted) and the fee is refunded. So you will have to wait and see.

Comment: What is your nationality and where do you live?

Answer (score 5):

This is a very dynamic and unprecedented situation, so nobody knows for sure what will happen.  So below is more of an opinion rather than known fact.

As it currently stands, travel into the 26 EU states as well as Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway and Switzerland, is prohibited for 30 days and as such travel is banned for all non-EU citizens or residents (except UK citizens).

Assuming your travel request falls within this period then the following is likely.

- They could reject you current application and tell you to reapply in
  the future.  That this rejection will not be looked upon negatively
  when you apply, and you should get a full refund of any fees paid.
- Or they could put your application on hold and ask you in the future
  if you wish to proceed or not with new dates.  If not, then you would
  get a full refund.
- They could approve your visa, but issue it with different dates and/or
  an extended travel period.  e.g.  instead of 90 in 180 days, then 90
  in 270 days.

If your travel request is for later than this period then the following could occur:

- Issue the visa but advise you that you will only be able to travel if
  the borders reopen.  If the borders don't reopen in time, you have to
  apply again.  You may or may not have to pay the fees again in such a case.
- Stop processing and ask you if you wish to postpone or withdraw your
  application, and refund the fees
- Stop processing temporarily.  Continue processing when the situation
  improves, if your application is far enough in the future
- Reject the application, and tell you to reapply again when the situation is clearer.  Refund the fees.

If the visa is rejected due to the Corona shutdown, then it will not be looked upon negatively when you apply again in the future and you should get a full refund.

Answer (score 1):

I applied for Netherlands visa from Pakistan, today I received the passport with a visa for 45 duration Multiple entry until 22 May, 2020. I must say that they cannot reject the visa on the base of corona.

Comment: Do double check that you can actually travel, as there is talk that the whole of the Schengen area will close the outside borders, including closing airport entry.

Comment: The question was about the application process, so I commented that I dont think that they can reject your visa for corona cause. Although many statements have been recorded but there is no official news about the border close yet. And about my plan, Im not travelling on this visa. Probably re apply.

Comment: "Although many statements have been recorded but there is no official news about the border close yet." - actually, plenty of news outlets have been reporting for the past hour or so that the decision has been made to close borders for 30 days - e.g. ["European Union member nations agreed Tuesday to close the EU’s external borders for 30 days in a dramatic new effort to slow the spread of the coronavirus pandemic"](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/03/17/coronavirus-european-union-leaders-agree-to-close-borders.html).

Answer (score 1):

R.B, I also submitted my application last Friday in London for France and I got my passport today with a rejection piece of paper. I've had 5 Schengen visas in the past and I was surprised when I saw that it wasn't issued this time.

The piece of paper said that due to the current situation and the outbreak of the virus, the consulate decided to not issue the visa and the fees will not be reimbursed, which is absurd. Ideally they should have either put the application on hold or not issue the visa (understandable given the decision of the EU of closing the Schengen space) and refund the visa fees. Instead, I got the passport back and no refund.

I will be complaining to the embassy (I don't think TLS had anything to do with this) and I hope that they will either refund people or reprocess their applications in the future for no feed.